# Self executing coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Self invoking Coffeescript

```
$ -> 
  alert "Hello CoffeeScript!"
```

Compiles to

```
$(function() {
  return alert("Hello CoffeeScript!");
});
```

Now, the same code -- $ replaced with any other variable -->

```
hello= -> 
  alert "Hello CoffeeScript!"
```

Above code - Does not execute by itself.

**How does giving a `$` variable enable self execution(jQuery lib not included)?** (is jQuery is playing a role here?)

I know you've to use `do` to have self invoking functions in `coffeescript` --- that's not my question ( please do not duplicate it ).

-coffeescript beginner

Comment: I assume the `=` after `hello` is a typo? Otherwise, you *haven't* just swapped `hello` in for `$`, you've changed the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is **not** self-executing. It's just giving jQuery a function reference. It's **jQuery** that calls that function, later, when the DOM is ready (or right away if it already is).

Details [in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

> How does giving a `$` variable enable self execution(jQuery lib not included)?

If the function is being called, jQuery clearly *is* included (or something else that defines a function and attaches it to `$` and calls the function you pass it).

> (is jQuery is playing a role here?)

Yes.

---

> I know you've to use `do` to have self invoking functions in coffeescript

If you mean *immediately*-invoked rather than *self*-invoked (a common misnomer), no, you don't:

```
(() ->
  alert 'Hello!'
)()
```

...which translates to:

```
(function() {
  return alert('Hello!');
})();
```

...which defines a function and invokes it immediately.

Or if you really meant **self**-invoking (e.g., recursive):

```
(foo = (n) ->
  alert 'Call ' + n
  if n > 0
    foo(n - 1);
)(10)
```

...which translates to:

```
var foo;

(foo = function(n) {
  alert('Call ' + n);
  if (n > 1) {
    return foo(n - 1);
  }
})(10);
```

...which defines a function that calls itself 10 times.

Comment: I was trying the code on coffeescript.org's complier, $( callback ) is calling the function - then, coffeescript.org's comipler has jquery included by default?

Comment: @VivekChandra: No, it's not the compiler. The compiler does not know anything about `$` (nor about jQuery). It just compiles your coffeescript code to an invocation of the `$` function. *When that is executed*, jQuery does its job.

Comment: @bergi So, jQuery library is present in the coffeescript's tryCoffeescript tab. Understood, thanks.

Comment: @VivekChandra: That's right, it's the CoffeeScript website that has it, a fairly outdated version. Try `alert typeof jQuery` in it (shows "object"), or `alert jQuery.fn.jquery` which will show you (at present) `"1.6.4"`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow, that confirms it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing special about the `$` identifier. The actual difference between your snippets is the `=` after the identifier - without, it calls it with a function as the argument, with it the function gets assigned.

```
hello -> 
  alert "Hello CoffeeScript!"
// compiles to:
hello(function() {
  return alert("Hello CoffeeScript!");
});
```

```
hello = -> 
  alert "Hello CoffeeScript!"
// compiles to:
var hello;
hello = function() {
  return alert("Hello CoffeeScript!");
};
```

So if your `hello` function does invoke the given callback (as [`$` does](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)), your function expression will get executed in the first case (without the assignment).

Notice that this is not a "self-invocation", as it's `hello`/`$` that would call the function. For an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1048572) (which is usually referred to as "self-invoking"), you'd use [Coffeescripts `do` keyword](http://coffeescript.org/#loops).

Comment: Pretty sure that's a typo. But even with (or without) the `=`, it won't **call** itself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yeah, i was going to comment on that. +1 on your answer by then :-)

Comment: I was trying the code on coffeescript.org's complier, not sure if jquery is included there. But, hello doesnt call itself.

Comment: Well, probably you didn't define any `hello` function before it tried to call it.